# PInvoke behaves irrationally

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I wrote a dll in c and i use it in c# using p/invoke

Here is an example of two functions in the dll:

```
   __declspec(dllexport) int init()
    {
         int *pointer=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
         return *pointer;
    }

   __declspec(dllexport) void add(int item)
    {
         int *pointer=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
         pointer=&item;
    }
```

Here is the define of the dll import in c#:

```
[DllImport("c_code.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int init();

[DllImport("c_code.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void add(int item);
```

Now `init` works well but `add` throws an exception:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory
>
> This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Did I do something wrong?

I even deleted the whole content of the add function and it still does that,is there something wrong in my usage of p/invoke? i am thinking it'a a problem in the usage of the p\invoke.

Also I run it on a x64 pc if it is matter

NOTE: what is in the function doesn't matter because even if they are empty it still occurs I gave this simple example that should work but for some crazy reason it doesn't

Comment: I find this hard to believe. That said both of your functions are rather pointless.

Comment: i know it's crazy,i didn't give my whole code it would be too long but this is still the signature of the functions and if i change them to what i wrote here i still get the same problem

Comment: If the error occurs with an empty add, why did you put code in the one you included here? Are you sure this is the real code?

Comment: it is not the real code but it doesn't matter,i even edited the function to be like the questions and i still get the same error even if add is empty

Comment: The code in the Q won't give the error you describe.

Comment: in my ide it does,i think it's a problem in the usage of the p\invoke and i don't know what i did worng

Comment: i am using the visual studio compiler

Comment: IIRC, C likes to pass by value. When you get the address of `item` in `add` you are getting the address of a temporary value, probably on the stack. Or I'm way off base.

Comment: How do you export the `add()` function from your C DLL? The problem might be related to the calling convention used.

Comment: @HABO That doesn't matter. Reading an address of a variable on the stack is perfectly fine. It's not as if the address is returned to the caller which then uses it.

Comment: i am using the cdecl convention for the functions

Comment: Just writing `void add(int item)` will not export the `add()` function from your DLL. You must explicitly export it (using a *.def file, using `__declspec(dllexport)` or some other means). With the sample code you give in your question, `add()` never is exported in the first place.

Comment: i edit it again i am using __declspec(dllexport) i just forgot to write it here

Comment: I fixed your edit. It is spelled `DllImport`. These details matter. If you cannot get them right it makes it look like you are making it all up.

Comment: i know it matters,in my code it is spelled correctly i just write it wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question does not result in the errors that you report. The problem lies somewhere else in your program, in code that is not present in the question.

It is most likely that the other code corrupts the heap or stack, but the error does not manifest until the functions you show here are called.

The other plausible explanation is that the code in the question is different from the code you are running. That is certainly quite conceivable, not least because the code in the question does not compile.

Looking at the code in the question though, it is rather dubious. The `init` function returns an uninitialized `int`. And the `add` function leaks memory, and makes a pointless assignment to a local variable that immediately leaves scope. However, neither of those will lead to the error you report.

Comment: first of all the code in the question should compile,second and i can't stress this enough even if both the functions are completely empty and i mean something like:int add(int item){} it still doesn't work

Comment: Let me tell you that, yes the code should compile, but it does not. If you had tried to compile it you would know that. It is `dllimport` rather than `DllImport`. And, when the functions are empty, or as you have them, they do not lead to an error. This is easy enough for you to see for yourself. Make brand new projects, and add the code in the Q to it, and then fix it so that it compiles.

Comment: i misspelled in the Q,it does compile and when they are empty they do lead to the error i swear

Comment: Swear all you like, but you are wrong. Find out for yourself by making a brand new project and adding these functions to it. Please come back when you've done that and report what you found. Note that I have done so. I already know what happens.

Comment: Two empty functions whose signature perfectly match the p/invoke, and that have the correct calling convention, cannot result in that error. And of course they don't. You need to start with a brand new empty Win32 project of DLL type. Then add the code in the Q. Then call it from a brand new C# project. Just like I did. Try to appreciate that I've done p/invoke before: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pinvoke/topusers  Perhaps if you see that then you might appreciate what I am telling you

Comment: i am appreciate what you are telling me but i am trying to understand why it doesn't work instead of opening another project,i know that it should lead to that error but i looked again and again and i don't know why it doesn't work,still thanks for your help

Comment: Please do as I say. Create that new project. Prove to yourself that the code in the Q is fine. Then you will be able to accept the first paragraph of my answer as the truth. And then, you'll be able to look at the code that is not in the question to work out why your project, with the code that we cannot see, has a problem.

Comment: i am using the code in the question in my program and it doesn't work

Comment: As I explained in the answer, that's because of the other code in the program that is in your program, that you can see, that is not here in this question, and that we cannot see. The code in the question is fine. The problem is elsewhere. I cannot make you believe me. If you would do the experiment I asked you to do then you might believe me.

Comment: david there is no other code i am calling from the dll,sure there are more functions but i don't call them or use them in the c# or in the functions in the Q i use just those t'o as i wrote them in the Q i did the experiment and it worked of course but it doesn't make sense

Comment: I guess you next need to cut it all down until you cut away something that also makes the problem vanish. You do need to isolate and identify a minimal amount of code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: that is what i did. i cut the add and init functions to find out if the problem was in the c code or in the import and in the end i got down to two empty functions and still the error,i will try to open a new project and transfer the code maybe it will help